# Constant already defined in function prototype

Tags: php, function, constants

I have this code :

```php
<?php

define('LOG_DEBUG','DEBUG');
define('LOG_ERROR','ERROR');

function trace($message,$level=LOG_DEBUG){
    echo '['.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' '.$level.'] '.$message."\n";
}

trace('test debug message');
trace('test error message', LOG_ERROR);
```

Output (Running in PHP 7.4) :

```
PHP Notice:  Constant LOG_DEBUG already defined in /var/www/mail_dumper/PHPMailDumper.php on line 3
[2022-02-11 22:00:33 7] test debug message
[2022-02-11 22:00:33 ERROR] test error message
```

I don't understand the notice...

I tried to affect LOG_DEBUG to default value and not try to reaffect?

And... In trace test we see a "7" in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this warning because [`LOG_DEBUG`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/network.constants.php) is a predefined PHP constant for the [`syslog`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php) function.